# JetBrains Rider Crashes when Evaluating

Tags: jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-rider

For some reason Rider simply freezes when evaluating an expression:

[image]

Yes,the string result is pretty large.

Is there a remedy for this?
Works fine in VS2019

Comment: Same issue here, I have an object that is ~5 KB when serialised. Rider crashes and is stuck on 'Evaluating'